# Refresh page on new user sign in when using Google oAuth 2.0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-signin, google-oauth

I'm trying to make a website using [Google Sign For Websites.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project) Mostly just for the sake of learning about how it works.

I've followed the steps outlined in that tutorial Google Provides which works fine. Users can successfully sign into my site, it is able to pass the users ID to the backend and then verify the ID server side using a php script.

Php then creates a session for the user on the website. What I can't figure out is how would I refresh the page when a user clicks the Google Sign in button and the sign in is successful. Refreshing the page would allow the home page to be reloaded with the new php session data.

```
<div class="g-signin2 signin-button" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>

function onSignIn(googleUser){

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'https://mywebsite.com/tokensignin.php');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onload = function() {
            console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
        };
        xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
      };
```

I've tried using simply `location.reload()` inside of the onload = function() portion of the code. This causes the page to just infinately refresh every time it is loaded however since Google verifys that the user is signed in through this `xhr` variable every time.

I've tried [looking through their reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthissignedinlistenlistener) to use `GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(listener)` to monitor any changes but it doesn't seem to fullfull what I want it to or I'm not using it correctly since I don't exactly know what the listener should be.

The other option might be to use their `GoogleAuth.attachClickHandler(container, options, onsuccess, onfailure)` function but I'm not entirely sure how the properly configure the options field/variable.

If someone could provide some insight as to how this world work I would greatly appreciate it.

To summarize if the user is already signed into my website using Google I want the page to do nothing, if they click the signin button, after the sign in is successful I want to refresh the page they are on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a listener to xhr with a callback function.

```
xhr.addEventListener("load", loginComplete);
```

And then create a function:

```
function loginComplete(evt) {
    console.log("Login Complete");
    window.location.reload(); 
}
```

EDIT:

Ok. Since the listener doesn't help. You will need to check if the user is already logged in. To save that information one thing I could think of would be using cookies.

So you could store the Auth Token you receive from Google and set a cookie for it and check everytime before you make your POST.

Here is a nice js cookie library: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Then onload you save the id:

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    Cookie.set('google_token', id_token);
    window.location.reload();
};
```

And the onSignIn function would be like:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser){
    var cookie = Cookie.get('google_token');
    if(cookie != undefined){
        //cookie is set
        return;
    }
    ...
    //rest of the function
}
```

Of course you need to improve this code, for example, check if the token stored in the cookies is still valid, some cases you can just refresh it instead of making the user log in again (the oAuth API provide such things).

Make some security measures to be sure the token is not being injected and etc..

Comment: This still does not solve the problem because it still creates an infinite loop of page refreshes. It will trigger the refresh when the button is clicked and the login is finished. However once the refresh has finished the page loads it sends the request again. Since every time the page is loaded Google processes the login to see if the user is still signed into the site. If they are signed into the site the login completes successfully. Which then causes the login to be 'completed' again.

Comment: I will give this a try when I have time in the next day or two. I think this will likely become the most reliable method. I've done some additional experimenting with the API the last day or so. There are some functions that look for changes in user state such as GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen but those pose some of the already existing problems. The listen for a state change is checked each time the page is loaded, again creating the infinite loop of refreshes. A cookie to check for a new vs already signed in, paired along with sessions to validate data will be an easy and secure way to do this

Comment: Another idea that you could look into is using a framework to build your website, like React or Vue. They all have packages to handle this kind of thing and a lot more. It is just too much work that you put on that you could be focusing in some other crucial stuff. I personally use Laravel to handle all my backend, including token based authentication, and it was really easy to get this working...

Comment: Using one of or a combination of those frameworks is the best way to handle something like this in the long run I agree. In principle though handling this via cookies to determine a fresh login is the best method I've found. People should follow the Google API documentation to verify that tokens are valid and secure. The combination of all this allows it to function successfully. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

My approach was the same as yours and I indeed ran into the same problem with constant refreshing.

I tried a couple of solutions, the best working one was as follows:

- User signs in using GAPI2 triggering callback `onGoogleSignIn`
- Backend checks ID token validity, and signs user in through session on my webapp
- If successful, I *log the user out* using GAPI2, preventing infinite reload, because `onGoogleSignIn` is never called again
- Then I refresh the page and replace the sign-in button with a logout button for my webapp

This solution is of course pretty much useless if you want to manipulate some data on user's Google account, but I found no use for this functionality.

---

Code for signing someone out of their google account.

```
function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        console.log('User signed out.');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your back end redirect (or send info so the page so it can redirect on success)?

What is the need for reloading the login screen?

You could also check out the listener documentation it seems like this may solve what you want. ie. listen for user change and trigger a function or redirect.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners